# "net user XXX /expires:never" does not work in Active Directory mode

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-command-prompt

I'm trying to make a user's password never expire, so I executed the following command in the domain controller:

```
net user admin /expires:never
```

And it succeed.

But months later, the password still gets expired, what should I do in command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use AD cmdlets to do this:

```perl
    Set-ADUser -Identity username -PasswordNeverExpires $true
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `/domain` argument should work:

```
net user admin /expires:never /domain
```